Question About Possible Ver 14.0 Bug
All: I'm running the following code. It's coming up with a persistent bug that seems to be related to the graph and processing the information; see image. Any advice? This code works fine with Ver 13.3.
T = {{3/4, 1/4}, {1/3, 2/3}};
T // MatrixForm
n = 2;
rootnode = 1;
MatrixPower[T, n] // MatrixForm
g = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0}, T];
Graph[g, VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> 
    MarkovProcessProperties[g, "TransitionMatrix"][[i, j]]}]
step[_, _, 0] := {}
step[T_, p : (_ -> i_), n_] := 
 Flatten@Table[
   If[T[[i, j]] > 
     0, {Property[p -> (p -> j), EdgeLabels -> T[[i, j]]], 
     step[T, p -> j, n - 1]}, Nothing], {j, Length@T}]
Graph[step[MarkovProcessProperties[g, "TransitionMatrix"], 
  Begin -> rootnode, n], VertexStyle -> Yellow, VertexSize -> 0.5, 
 VertexLabels -> {(_ -> j_) :> Placed[j, {1/2, 1/2}]}]

g2 = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{0, 1}, 
   MatrixPower[MarkovProcessProperties[g, "TransitionMatrix"], n]];
Graph[g2, VertexStyle -> {1 -> Yellow, 2 -> Yellow}, 
 EdgeLabels -> {DirectedEdge[i_, j_] :> 
    MarkovProcessProperties[g2, "TransitionMatrix"][[i, j]]}]



It works properly under version 14.0.0.0 with nice yellow circles. Have you tried restarting the Mathematica ?

OK in 14.1 on Windows.
